# Rstudio: How to do a barplot in which bars size shows a production value (0-380 t/ha) and inside them the area proportion of each shown species?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm new using R and analyzing the data, so I need advice... I have an annual production of four zones of a plantation, each with a different area ratio of genetic material used (3 var). I have been thinking of plotting all this information on a bar chart.

I am thinking that the size of the bar shows the production so x-axis is only for this data. And within each bar to show the area ratio for each species. But I am struggling a lot, what do you think?

[image]

```
 data <- data.frame(
  Site = rep(c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"), each = 3),
  Species = rep(c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3"), times = 4),
  Production = c(385.8, 309.8, 274.8, 102.6),
  AreaProportion_Sp1 = c(0.835, 1, 0.274, 0.168),
  AreaProportion_Sp2 = c(0.164, 0, 0.074, 0),
  AreaProportion_Sp3 = c(0, 0, 0.65, 0.83)
)


I tried this helped by chatGTP: 

 data <- data.frame(
  Site = rep(c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"), each = 3),
  Species = rep(c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3"), times = 4),
  Production = c(385.808421662597, 309.8087515, 274.827019, 102.6782627),
  AreaProportion_Sp1 = c(0.835, 1, 0.274, 0.168),
  AreaProportion_Sp2 = c(0.164, 0, 0.074, 0),
  AreaProportion_Sp3 = c(0, 0, 0.65, 0.83)
)

real_data<- gather(real_data, key = "Species", value = "AreaProportion", -Site, -Production)
ggplot(real_data, aes(x = Site, y = Production, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(AreaProportion), y = as.numeric(Production) / 2),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Annual Production with Area Proportion",
       x = "Site",
       y = "Annual Production",
       fill = "Species") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: What is your specific question here? Are you asking for data visualization advice? That's off topic for Stack Overflow. This site is for specific programming questions. You should know exactly what you want to plot when asking here. A site like [stats.se] lists data visualization as on topic. Otherwise what exactly do you want to change about the current code? What does the desired output look like?

Comment: @MrFlick I think the problem is that the plot is simply wrong, caused by the actual data in the data frame being recycled due to the OP trying to add a long-format "Species" column. If we assume the relevant data frame is actually just four rows representing four sites, the structure makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your data frame is wrong. You have 4 sites, a total production yield from each site, and the proportion of that yield contributed by each of 3 species. However, the `Species` column is a different length from the other columns, causing it to be recycled, as is the `site` column. This seems to have been done in an attempt to pivot your data into long format.

Let's keep it simple and just input the data at each site and for each species:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  Site = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"),
  Production = c(385.8, 309.8, 274.8, 102.6),
  AreaProportion_Sp1 = c(0.835, 1, 0.274, 0.168),
  AreaProportion_Sp2 = c(0.164, 0, 0.074, 0),
  AreaProportion_Sp3 = c(0, 0, 0.65, 0.83)
)
```

Now we can take this data, pivot it into long format, filter out the species absent at each site, and create some percentage labels too:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Area"), names_sep = "Proportion_", 
               names_to = c(".value", "Species")) %>%
  mutate(Production = Production * Area,
         Species = gsub("Sp", "Species ", Species),
         label = scales::percent(Area, 0.1)) %>%
  filter(Area > 0) %>%
  select(-Area)
```

Now we have a very simple data frame to use for our plot

```r
plot_data
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   Site  Production Species   label 
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <chr> 
#> 1 B1         322.  Species 1 83.5% 
#> 2 B1          63.3 Species 2 16.4% 
#> 3 B2         310.  Species 1 100.0%
#> 4 B3          75.3 Species 1 27.4% 
#> 5 B3          20.3 Species 2 7.4%  
#> 6 B3         179.  Species 3 65.0% 
#> 7 B4          17.2 Species 1 16.8% 
#> 8 B4          85.2 Species 3 83.0%
```

And we can plot it with whichever stylistic attributes we like

```r
ggplot(plot_data, aes(Site, Production, fill = Species, color = Species)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), position = position_stack(0.5),
            fontface = 2, size = 5, key_glyph = draw_key_blank) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Production at each site, showing contribution per species")
```

[image]